# What is channeling efficiency, and what does it do?

Tags: warframe

So, most mods that had "Charge speed" or "charge damage" have now been replaced with "Channeling efficiency" as a stat.

What does Channeling efficiency do?  When it says "+30% Channeling Efficiency", what exactly is happening? Does it mean it costs less energy per melee hit while channeling, does it mean I get more damage out of channeling, does it have any other effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Channeling Efficiency reduces the cost per hit while channeling (holding left mouse button while having the sword equipped).

Base cost is 5 energy per hit (misses do not use energy), minimum energy cost is set to 1 Energy per strike, so even if you should get 100% channelig Efficiency, you can't get below that cap.

Also not that you can gain a damage multiplier while chanelling - ever 5 consecutive hits earns you a damage multiplier of 0.5 (I don't know if there is a cap).

Source: [Warframe Wikia](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Reflex_Coil)

[Warframe forum](https://forums.warframe.com/index.php?/topic/215437-channeling-and-energy-drain/)

Comment: so what's my best bet for Channeling Efficiency in terms of limits? For example, p efficiency is limited by 75% or 65% i believe, so going over doesn't affect energy spent anymore, what about channeling? Is it 100% as a cap?

Comment: As per the wiki - Power Efficiency is capped at 80%, which translates to 1 energy per hit while channeling.

Answer (score 2):

Channeling happens when you hold down the left mouse button while in melee mode, and (at base) converts 5 Energy into extra damage on your next melee hit.

Channeling Efficiency reduces the amount of energy each hit consumes to a minimum of 1 Energy per hit, so "30% channel efficiency" would mean your attacks consume 5*0.7=3.5 energy per strike.